# Eclipse Tomcat7 Server Doesnt support Remote Host

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat7, enterprise, remote-access

My Problem is: When I try to add my Tomcat7 to Eclipse EE as a server, I get an error message that says:

> "The currently selected server type does not support remote hosts"

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Or how to enable remote hosts in Tomcat?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Tomcat support in Eclipse is meant for running Tomcat locally on your own machine.  That's necessary because Eclipse deploys web modules to Tomcat by copying them into a folder in the Tomcat installation.  It can't deploy things to a remote Tomcat server because it can't copy files into a folder on a different computer.

Typically you'd run Tomcat on your own computer for development, and then (manually) deploy your application to a remote server when you want to make it available to the rest of the world.

Comment: what a pity that eclipse cant copy to remote.

Comment: I used to do this in previous versions. Now I use neon, that's ridiculous and a big regression.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

As you can see in the image the "**server host name**" field is "**localhost**" which is correct parameter value.

**Solution:-**
in your case it would have been showing something like "**cloud**" or something else. please make sure that you pass correct value which is "**localhost**".

Answer (score 5):

i also faced this issue .my case is "i already have created tomcat server and my tomcat server(8) is installation location is

> "c:/xyz/apache-tomcat-8.0.28"

then i changed my tomcat server(8)  location to another place `

> "c:/abc/apache-tomcat-8.0.28"

`after that when i try to create new tomcat server 8.then it showing this error 
i solved by changing server runtime Environments in **eclipse**

> preferences => server => Runtime Environments
>   [image]

then select your tomcat type .you can remove the server and  add new server runtime Environment or edit existing one by giving correct tomcat installation path.then it won't give `"The currently selected server type does not support remote hosts"` error.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When you add Tomcat to Eclipse as a server runtime, don't forget to check "Create a new local server".

Answer (score 2):

While defining new Server in eclipse

In server host name box use localhost instead of cloud.

Answer (score 0):

for me I had renamed the tomcat folder after installing and was getting this error message with STS and Tomcat 6. See bobthemagicman's answer here: [Eclipse Juno Tomcat 6 Remote Host Not Supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063456/eclipse-juno-tomcat-6-remote-host-not-supported)

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the temp file in your workspace.
*...workspace\ .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp-data*

then make a new server with a new server runtime environment.

Answer (score 0):

Just change Server's Host Name to **LOCALHOST**

See here

[image: eclipse image]