# Eclipse Juno Tomcat 6 Remote Host Not Supported

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, tomcat6

I am trying to add a tomcat 6 server in my eclipse juno but I am getting this error:

```
The currently selected server type does not support remote hosts
```

Before juno I had galileo on the same machine and I was able to add tomcat 6 successfully in it without any problems.

I searched on the internet before asking but the only relevant link i got was this:
[Eclipse Tomcat7 Server Doesnt support Remote Host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444893/eclipse-tomcat7-server-doesnt-support-remote-host)
and it doesn't help much.

Pls help
Thanks

Comment: Not so loud ! Why do you write with UPPERCASE LETTERS ???

Comment: ohh sorry I didnt mean to be rude .... I just thought the subject should be in caps

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Tomcat 7 and I solved it by importing a Tomcat 7 project from another workspace which already had the server set up. Additionally I added a Runtime Environment for Apache Tomcat 7 (Window > Preferences > Server > Runtime Environments > Add)

Comment: Going in Window > Preferences > Server > Runtime Environments > Add did it for me. Thnx for the tip

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same problem and it was because I had a previous version of tomcat installed, upgraded to a newer version, deleted to old one, and never changed the runtime environment in Eclipse. It's kind of a poor error message because it doesn't state the true nature of the problem but anyway... The easiest way to fix this is:

Open Eclipse, right click on the workspace and select New Server.

Once you are at the *Define New Server* wizard click on Apache and select Tomcat 6. This is where you should see the error *The currently selected server type does not support remote hosts*. Now below server runtime environment click *Configure Runtime Environments* and new popup will open. You should see Apache Tomcat v6.0 in the preferences window. Select this and click edit to the right.

You will have a new popup titled Edit Server Runtime Environment. Under Tomcat Installation Directory you can browse to the location of the tomcat directory. Assuming you have downloaded Tomcat and put it at the top level of your C: drive you should have something like this: *C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.36*. Click finish and you should be good to go. Let us know how it works out for you!

Comment: hey I tried using the way you told me .... but strangely this time I received no error .. I was able to add the server

Comment: It didn't work for me. I'm using Tomat 7.0.52. The error dissapears, but it doesn't let me push the button finish, as it appears deactivated.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem and tried to follow @dbk's solution but I didn't have the "Configure Runtime Environments" in the wizard screen. For me I needed to go to preferences->server->run time environments where I had incorrectly configured runtime environments. So to be clear if you have runtime environments that are not configured correctly you will have to edit them first.