# cannot add server(tomcat) to eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

Environment : Windows + Eclipse Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2) + Tomcat 8 + JDK 8

When I try to add a new server to Eclipse with `File -> New -> Other -> Server`

I choice the `"Tomcat v8.0 Server"` in "New Server" dialog, and I have added "Server Runtime Environments". but there is a error message

> " The currently selected server type does not support remote hosts".

what can I do with this error?

thanks everybody!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444893/eclipse-tomcat7-server-doesnt-support-remote-host

Answer (score 6):

I solved by changing server runtime environments in eclipse, 
`Preferences => Server => Runtime Environments`

[image]

then select your tomcat type. You can remove the server and add new server runtime Environment or edit existing one by giving correct tomcat installation path. Then it won't give

> "The currently selected server type does not support remote hosts" error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the server name to `localhost`.

Comment: sorry  , it's server name

Comment: If you can comment, you can edit. Do that next time instead.